# How to determine if 4 points are on same plane

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm choosing 4 points from an image outputted by Kinect therefor each point has its `(x, y, z)` coordinates.

My objective is to determine whether the 4 points fall on the same plane.

This is my function:

```
    public bool isValidPlane()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < edgesPoints.Length; i++)
        {
            double absPlaneEquation = Math.Abs(distance -
                (normal.X * edgesPoints[i].X + normal.Y * edgesPoints[i].Y + normal.Z * edgesPoints[i].Z));
            if (absPlaneEquation > 1500) /* 1500 is a tolerance error*/
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The `normal` is also the normal (a cross product of 2 vectors on the plane, which been previously calculated from 3 out of 4 of the chosen points) to the plane and it's normalized:

```
    private void calcPlaneNormalVector()
    {
        if (lastEdgeNumber < 3)
        {
            return;
        }
        Vector3D vec1 = new Vector3D(edgesPoints[0], edgesPoints[1]);
        Vector3D vec2 = new Vector3D(edgesPoints[0], edgesPoints[2]);
        vec2 = vec1.crossProduct(vec2);
        double lengthNormal = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(vec2.X, 2) + Math.Pow(vec2.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(vec2.Z, 2));
//normalizing:
        normal = new Vector3D((vec2.X / lengthNormal), (vec2.Y / lengthNormal), (vec2.Z / lengthNormal));
        distance = (-1) * (edgesPoints[0].X * normal.X + edgesPoints[0].Y * normal.Y + edgesPoints[0].Z + normal.Z);
    }
```

`Vector3D` is a class to represent a vector:

```
public  class Vector3D
{
    private double x, y, z;

    public Vector3D(Point3D p1, Point3D p2)
    {
        x = p2.X - p1.X;
        y = p2.Y - p1.Y;
        z = p2.Z - p1.Z;
    }
    public Vector3D(double a = 0, double b = 0, double c = 0)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }

    <get properties for x, y, z >

    public Vector3D crossProduct(Vector3D u)
    {
        double tmpX = 0, tmpY = 0, tmpZ = 0;
        tmpX = y * u.Z - z * u.Y;
        tmpY = z * u.X - x * u.Z;
        tmpZ = x * u.Y - y * u.X;
        return new Vector3D(tmpX, tmpY, tmpZ);
    }
    public double dotProduct(Vector3D u)
    {
        return x * u.X + y * u.Y + z * u.Z;
    }
}
```

i always get `1300 <= absPlaneEquation <= 1400` even when the 4 points are chosen so that they won't be on the same plane.

What is the best way to detect that the 4 points refer to the same plane?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if four points are on the same plane, only by using distances (verify colinearity)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426748/check-if-four-points-are-on-the-same-plane-only-by-using-distances-verify-coli)

Comment: @MattWilko, this is not a duplicate. The question you posted is more theoretical, here i'm puting more imphasis on the technical implementation.  Moreover, with kinect there is a degree of error unlike the ideal situation with the question you stated.

Comment: Actually that question has an accepted solution which contains a C++ function to calculate exactly what you are seeking. That looks like it would convert to C# without about three characters being changed.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but here's an article on how to do this (more from a mathematical perspective than a computer science perspective but still...): https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-way-to-determine-if-4-points-lie-on-the-same-plane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have the normal vector of a plane, you can evaluate the plane's equation:

```
normal vector components : [A, B, C]
Plane equation           : A·x + B·y + C·z + D = 0;
```

Use one of the three points (`P1`, `P2` or `P3`) used to obtain the normal vector to evaluate `D` and then simply check that the fourth point (`P4`) satisfies the equation:

```
 D = - (A·x1 + B·y1 + C·z1)
 A·x4 + B·y4 + C·z4 - (A·x1 + B·y1 + C·z1) = 0
```

It is importat to note that you are using *floating point arithmetics* so you can not test for strict equality. You need to define an acceptable error and check that the fourth points complies with the equation according to such tolerance:

```
 |A·x4 + B·y4 + C·z4 - (A·x1 + B·y1 + C·z1)| < TOLERANCE
```

UPDATE: Here's how I'd code the solution to your problem:

```
public struct Point3D
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
    public double Z { get; }

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}

public struct Vector3D
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
    public double Z { get; }
    public double Magnitude => Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z);

    public Vector3D(Point3D p1, Point3D p2)
        : this(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.Z - p1.Z)
    {
    }

    public Vector3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public static Vector3D CrossProduct(Vector3D left, Vector3D right)
    {
        double tmpX = 0, tmpY = 0, tmpZ = 0;
        tmpX = left.Y * right.Z - left.Z * right.Y;
        tmpY = left.Z * right.X - left.X * right.Z;
        tmpZ = left.X * right.Y - left.Y * right.X;
        return new Vector3D(tmpX, tmpY, tmpZ);
    }

    public static double DotProduct(Vector3D left, Vector3D right)
    {
        return left.X * right.X + left.Y * right.Y + left.Z * right.Z;
    }
}

public struct Plane3D
{
    private const double TOLERANCE = 0.001;

    private readonly double independentTerm;
    public Vector3D Normal { get; }

    public Plane3D(Point3D p1, Point3D p2, Point3D p3)
    {
        Normal = Vector3D.crossProduct(new Vector3D(p1, p2), new Vector3D(p1, p3));

        if (Normal.Magnitude < TOLERANCE)
            throw new ArgumentException("Specified points do not define a valid plane.");

        independentTerm = -(Normal.X * p1.X + Normal.Y * p1.Y + Normal.Z * p1.Z);
    }

    public bool Contains(Point3D p) => Math.Abs(Normal.X * p.X + Normal.Y * p.Y + Normal.Z * p.Z + independentTerm) < TOLERANCE;
}
```

Things to note:

1. I've changed `Point3D` and `Vector3D` to structs. This largely depends on how you will use the objects but, at first glance, value types seem a better fit.
2. I've made the value types immutable. Mutable value types are not a good idea; again, this wouldn't be an issue if you implement them as classes although I'd still advise creating immutable types whenever possible. In this case, doing so is very cheap.
3. You have the concept of *plane*, well then, create a type to represent one.
4. I've changed the vector operators to `static` methods. This could be down to personal taste.
5. I've implemented the `TOLERANCE` const inside `Plane`. There is probably much better places where to define it, its simply there for convenience.
6. I've tweeked you naming slightly; public members should start with a capital letter.

Comment: if you look at my code, that's what i did. however, the problem is with the error value you get which yeilds non-precise values which makes this equation not applicable

Comment: @ThunderWiring No, it's not exactly what you are doing. Your are  normalizing vectors which is not necessary and can make the accumulated error bigger than necessary (for example if the modulus of the normal vector is very small). Apart from that, your are using floating point arithmetic, you can not test for equality; you need to define a tolerance and check that the equation is satisfied according to that tolerance: `Math.Abs(A·x4 + B·y4 + C·z4 - (A·x1 + B·y1 + C·z1)) <= TOLERANCE`.

Comment: please take another look at the code, i have this part: `if (absPlaneEquation > 1500) /* 1500 is a tolerance error*/
            {
                return false;
            }` Also, why normalizing make the accumulated error larger?

Comment: @ThunderWiring Your code is wrong;  `normal.Z` is added instead of multiplied to the corresponding point coordinate.

Comment: i've just noticed that in calculating the length i should've used `vec2` not `normal`. Are you referring to calculating the length? it's just the Petagoras way to calculate a length of the vector. Anyway, i was also interested about what you said regarding the error accumulation when normalizing.

Comment: @ThunderWiring Forget the error accumulation, I might have been too hasty claiming that particular issue. Just read my proposed algorithm carefully, implement it as is and your problems should be solved.

Comment: Your solution is more organized. I added a `Normalize` static function to `Vector3D` and omitted the condition that checks if `Magnitude < TOLERANCE` and got even better results! Thanks!

Comment: @ThunderWiring The check is there to make sure that the given points are not colinear; 3 colinear points do not define a unique plane. Whats probably happening is that your tolerance is way too high (`1500`), you should be using much smaller values when checking the magnitude.